# Как обновить состояние для всех пользователей в моем приложении чата Jetpack Compose при отправке сообщения?

Tags: android, state, viewmodel, android-jetpack-compose

Jetpack Compose. Проблема с обновлением состояния. Обновляется только у отправителя сообщения, но у других пользователей экран почему-то не обновляется. Я использую архитектуру MVI

В моей viewModel для экрана с чатом есть две функции, getMessages() срабатывает
сразу при открытии чата в launchedEffect с ключом Unit, то есть всего один раз. В getMessages() потом запускается корутина, где я обновляю state. У каждого пользователя в этот момент экран обновляется, сообщения отображаются. Но, когда отправляю сообщение, срабатывает событие, которое вызывает функцию sendMessage() во viewModel, там я обновляю state, я выяснил, что можно даже так его обновлять, getMessages() в корутине снова запускается и обновляет state. НО, проблема в том, что обновляется state только у отправителя сообщения, а у других пользователей нет, им нужно либо в клавиатуре что-то вести, либо перезапустить чат, чтобы state обновился.

Уже обращался много где со своей проблемой, но никто так и не смог внятно мне объяснить ничего. Мне сообщили, что можно каким-то образом подписаться на push, который я вызываю в своём repository:

```
override fun sendMessage(message: MessageModel) {
    messagesRef.push().setValue(message)
}
```

Но на что тут подписываться? Не ясно. Этот момент решили оставить без особых подробностей. Может кто-то сможет объяснить? Буду очень благодарен.

sendMessage() в ViewModel:

```
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
private fun sendMessage(text: String) {
    val calendar: Calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    val currentDate = LocalDate.now()

    val time = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm")
    val currentMonthName = currentDate.month.getDisplayName(
        TextStyle.FULL, Locale.getDefault()
    )

    val message = MessageModel(
        name = Firebase.auth.currentUser?.displayName.toString(),
        text = text,
        time = time.format(calendar.time),
        isMine = false,
        sender = Firebase.auth.currentUser?.uid.toString(),
        date = currentDate.dayOfMonth.toString() + " " + currentMonthName,
        isNewDate = false
    )

    viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.addMessage(message)

        _uiState.value.counter += 1
    }
}
```

getMessages() в ViewModel:

```
private fun getMessages() {
    _uiState.update { currentState ->
        currentState.copy(
            isLoading = true
        )
    }

    viewModelScope.launch {
        var i = 0
        repository.getMessages()
            .map { messages ->
                _messagesItemsSenders.add(messages.get(0).sender)
                _messagesDates.add(messages.get(0).date)
                _messagesPaddingMineAfterLastOther.add(messages.get(0).isMine)

                // Check for new sender
                if ((_messagesItemsSenders.size > 1) && (!messages.get(0).isMine) and
                        (_messagesItemsSenders[i] == _messagesItemsSenders[i-1])) {
                    messages.get(0).isMoreOne = true
                }

                // Check for new date
                messages.get(0).isNewDate =
                    !((_messagesDates.size > 1) && (_messagesDates[i] == _messagesDates[i-1]))

                // Set padding for first message that called "isMine"
                messages.get(0).isPaddingMine = (_messagesPaddingMineAfterLastOther.size > 1) &&
                        (messages.get(0).isMine) and
                        (_messagesPaddingMineAfterLastOther[i]
                                != _messagesPaddingMineAfterLastOther[i-1])

                i += 1
                ChatViewState(messages = messages, isLoading = false)
            }
            .collect() { newState ->
                _uiState.value = newState
            }
    }
```